# Cannot retrieve public post from Facebook Graph API v2.4 or higher

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

As show in the picture when I try to retrieve comments from the API "singular links API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher" error is given. I need to retrieve all the comments from the particular public post without any filtering.
[Image for Facebook singular links API error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnF6i.png)

Comment: There is no API for that

Comment: What do you mean by that exactly? If change the graph version to v2.3 I get what i need but on v2.8 is gives the error

Comment: Yes because the API changed.

Comment: You don't show what part of the API you are invoking here. An image link does not count. However, you should check here to see if your methods are deprecated: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog/

Comment: Wizkid are you saying there is no way I could get what I need?